# How to NOT print items in an Ansible loop error without no_log

Tags: ansible

When I execute an ansible module with a loop that has dictionaries with values to be used by the module, including confidential information, I can hide it using `loop_control.label`, but not when an error happens.

```yaml
- ansible.module:
    arg1: "{{ item.name }}"
    arg2: "{{ item.some_value }}"
    arg3: "{{ item.secret }}"
    arg4: "{{ item.throw_error }}"
  loop: 
    - name: "item1"
      some_value: "my value"
      secret: "p4$$w0rd"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.name }}"
```

I can hide it using `no_log: true`, but it then hides everything, including when a sucess happens, as well as the error message, that could be perfectly fine, and making me clueless about the actual error when I don't see it.

This is similar to stop all logs in a reverse proxy, or log everything, including authorization headers, both of which are far from desired in a production environment.

So, **is there a way to make it not log the loop items when an error occurs, but log everything else?** It could be either a task flag, just like `no_log`, or some global configuration, to include in the `ansible.cfg` file.

**Update (2021-04-19)**

The [answer from Vladimir](https://serverfault.com/a/1060165/415429) actually works as a workaround, but there are several downsides in using it:

1. You have to install the library `jmespath` prior to running `json_query` filter.
2. **It has more code and make the code as a whole less readable.**
3. If you have **lots** of loops (my specific project has over 80 of them), the code can become **really** ugly (also because of point 2).

4. If you have a loop in a parent file, you should use `loop_control` with `loop_var` in the debug loop.
5. The error and where it shows the error message will be different places. The same applies for success messages.
6. The loop `label` in the `debug` task will be different than the one in the main loop task (which may make it more difficult to associate success and error cases to the actual items).
7. The 2 tasks will be printed unnecessarily when everything is fine (with success messages printed separately from the actual tasks, making the output worse when everything runs successfully, which should be most cases).
8. Changing and testing the existing loop tasks, as well as making any new loops follow this format, will be a **maintenance burden** (especially because of point 2, that makes me think **if I'm actually improving** the code, or making it worse).

(and there are probably more downsides)

So the best I could say, is that this is a workaround that solves a problem and creates several others.

That said, I asked for a solution, and based on how Ansible works at the moment, the provided workaround (or some similar workaround) seems to be the only way to achieve what I asked.

I will weigh the pros and cons to see if I will implement this workaround, or if I continue to use it the way it is now.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to achieve desired behavior in multuple tasks with [ansible's error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#block-error-handling). You can `register` output of `no_log` task and print only non-secret part in subsequent `debug`:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - block:
    - shell: "/bin/false"
      loop:
      - name: "item1"
        some_value: "my value"
        secret: "p4$$w0rd"
      - name: "item2"
        some_value: "my value"
        secret: "p4$$w0rd"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
      # Capture tasks output
      register: my_task
      no_log: true

    # Run this if task above fails
    rescue:

    # Print msg, stderr or whatever needed
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_task | json_query('results[*].msg') }}"

    # finally fail a play
    - fail:
```

In case if you need always print output (not only on task failure) use `always` instead of `rescue` and `fail` task on condition:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - block:
    - shell: "/bin/true"
      loop:
      - name: "item1"
        some_value: "my value"
        secret: "p4$$w0rd"
      - name: "item2"
        some_value: "my value"
        secret: "p4$$w0rd"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item.name }}"
      register: my_task
      no_log: true

    always:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ my_task | json_query('results[*].msg') }}"

    - fail:
      when: my_task['failed'] | default(false)
```

**Update (2021-04-20)**

As pointed by Lucas code above have number of downsides. Main idea was that output can be registered and filtered afterwards. Other parts of code are opinionated examples. There is certainly room for improvement. For example here is code that addresses issues 1, 4, 6, (and partially 2):

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - block:
    - shell: "/bin/true"
      register: my_task
      no_log: true
      # Register all loop-related keys so same loop settings can be reused in debug
      <<: &loop
        loop:
        - name: "item1"
          some_value: "my value"
          secret: "p4$$w0rd"
        - name: "item2"
          some_value: "my value"
          secret: "p4$$w0rd"
        loop_control:
          label: "{{ item.name }}"
          index_var: index

    always:
    - debug:
        # match result with item by index
        msg: "{{ my_task['results'][index]['msg'] | default('ok') }}"
      # reuse loop from main task
      <<: *loop

    - fail:
      when: my_task['failed'] | default(false)
```

As for now it seems there is no way to implement desired behavior w/o workarounds. Ansible [recommends](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/logging.html) writing logs to secure location in case it contains sensitive data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I accepted it, as it seems the only way I can achieve what I asked is to use the provided workaround (or some similar workaround), although I edited my question to point several downsides of using this approach, especially in bigger projects with lots of tasks with loops. I will weigh the pros and cons to see if I will implement this workaround, or if I continue to use it the way it is now, but thanks for taking your time to post this answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, that solves points 1 and 6, and helps to minimize the downsides of points 2, 3, 4 and 5, although it's important to make sure that the debug task never errors, otherwise the items will show. But it's important to take care about the anchors in files with more than 1 loop, and especially when moving loops through files, when changing the code, to make sure each loop has its own uniquely named anchor.